# Import KPI from Analysis Service to Dashboard Designer directly without using Scorecard wizard

Tags: import, ssas, performancepoint, kpi, dashboard-designer

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010. When I create a new scorecard, Dashboard Designer gives option to import existing KPIs from Analysis Service. So if I make any changes to these KPIs in Analysis Service, then I create new scorecard and import the KPI. Is there any way to import the KPIs directly to Dashboard Designer without creating new scorecard.

Thanks in Advance,
Merin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new blank KPI --> Change the KPI data mapping to your SSAS data source --> Use a custom MDX tuple formula to reference your SSAS KPI's.

The tuple formulas you can use to get KPI data are KPIValue("[kpi name]"), KPITarget("[kpi name]"), KPIGoal("[kpi name"]), KPITrend("[kpi name"]).